# Developing a lotus notes database to read info of another database

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I am trying to develop a lotus notes database which can connect to another notes database and extract all the information like forms count, views etc.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?
Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to extract data, design or both?  A better description of circumstances would help too.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to extract design information from a Notes database, you can do this with Lotusscript or Java code.

The starting point would be a NotesNoteCollection (Lotusscript) / NoteCollection (Java) instance. You can read about this class, and the methods / properties available to you, in the Designer help file. Note collections can be used to extract documents as well as all design elements. Here's some sample Lotusscript:

```
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim db As NotesDatabase

Set db = session.CurrentDatabase

Dim nc As NotesNoteCollection
Set nc = db.CreateNoteCollection(False)

nc.SelectForms = True
Call nc.BuildCollection
```

You now have a collection of Notes forms, which you can iterate / manipulate as you see fit.

Answer (score -1):

Need to use webservice for this requreiment.